# Do wheels continue spinning when gear retracted?

Tags: landing-gear

Do landing gear wheels continue spinning inside the landing gear compartment once the gear has been retracted or is there a mechanism that will stop them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some aircraft have little friction skids that slow the wheels down, especially on nosewheels where there are not normally brakes.

On main and body gear, the brakes are (automatically on larger aircraft) momentarily applied during the retraction process to stop them from rotating.

Answer (score 3):

They continue spinning but there is a simple friction mechanism that immediately stops them. You can see how it works in [this video](https://youtu.be/x_yHtfGH0nI?t=650) at 10:50.